# Simple PHP card dealer. Having trouble with the unset command when shuffling deck

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I'm trying to learn PHP so I thought a simple card game would be a good start. I have 2 arrays, one for the suit and one for the card numbers, and I want to be able to represent every possible card combination in a random order, and then unset the array objects every time it shuffles to prevent duplication's. I have an example of the code below, but i'm receiving some errors on the unset function. Does anyone have a suggestion?

```
<?php

$suits = array ("clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades");

$faces = array (1 => "A", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13");

$deck = array();

foreach ($suits as $suit) {
    foreach ($faces as $face) {
        $deck[] = $face . "|" . $suit;
        unset($deck);
    }
}

shuffle($deck);

$card_num=5;

for($j=0; $j<$card_num; $j++) {    
      echo array_pop($deck).'<br>';

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `unset($deck);` while actually building up the `$deck` array.

Remove this line and your code should be fine.